# Unable to --watch directory with node-dev

Tags: node.js, nodemon, hotswap, node-dev

I am trying to watch only specific directories while starting `node-dev` because of the issue with multiple watches that causes;
`Error: watch /usr/src/app/node_modules/common-tags/lib/stripIndent/stripIndent.js ENOSPC`

I tried passing the `watch` flag but, the process is not able to find the module;

`node-dev --watch api app.js`

It throws the below error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'api' from '/usr/src/app'
    at resolveSync (/usr/src/app/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:89:15)
    at module.exports (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-dev/lib/resolve-main.js:4:10)
    at getConfig (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-dev/lib/cfg.js:30:16)
    at module.exports (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-dev/lib/cli.js:46:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/node-dev/bin/node-dev:11:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

The `api` directory is present in `/usr/src/app`. I tried using the same `watch` flag with `nodemon` and it seems to work but it has its own set of issues and crashes when a file change occurs.

I tried putting the configuration in `.node-dev.json`, but there has been no impact.

```
{
  "watch": ["api"],
  "ignore": [
    "*.test.js",
    "assets/*",
    "coverage/*",
    "docs/*",
    "email_templates/*",
    "kubernetes/*",
    "logs/*",
    "node_modules/*",
    "queue/*",
    "script/*",
    "shared/*",
    "tasks/*",
    "test/*",
    "tests/*",
    "uitests/*",
    "views/*"
  ]
}
```

Please note that I cannot modify `fs.inotify.max_user_watches` as the VM is shared and I don't have permission to run system commands.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you are not passing a js file to the watch parameter, *api* is a folder, not a module. try ```node-dev --watch api/app.js```

Comment: but the idea is to watch an entire directory (or directories), I tried something like `node-dev --watch api/*.js app.js`

Comment: the node-dev module does not scan for file to be watched. Its receive one root file and and just watch the files that are explicitly required. Font: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dev

Comment: thanks, @Victor_Maciel, the problem is that it is watching the entire source folder and the way we have structured it has all the front end and backend code. So, I was thinking, like `nodemon` if we can specify a directory to watch, it would be great. I am not sure why the `.node-dev.json` changes are being taken into effect. Breaking my head stackoverflow posts to github posts